# PYTHON: Noughts and Crosses

Tags: python, loops

I have created a multiplayer game of Noughts and Crosses using Python 3. 
I have got all of my code to work except for the check loop.

The check loop will each time a new symbol is entered if it is a winning move or if the board is full. 
Currently, my code does not finish after one player inputs 3 symbols in a row or the board becomes full.

This is my code so far:

```
import random

def start_player():

    startplayer = random.randint(1,2)
    if startplayer == 1:
        turn = 'X'
        print("Player One (X) will start the game.")
    else:
        startplayer == 2
        turn = 'O'
        print("Player Two (O) will start the game.")
    return turn

def getmove():

    row = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))
    column = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))
    while grid[row][column] != "":
        print("Invalid move.")
        row = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))
        column = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: ")) 
    return row, column

def mainturn(row, column):

    global countmove
    countmove = countmove + 1
    global symbol
    grid[row][column] = symbol

    for y in range(0,(len(grid))):
        print(grid[y])
    if symbol == 'X':
        symbol = 'O'
    elif symbol == 'O':
        symbol = 'X'
    return countmove

def check_win(row, column, symbol):    

    if (grid[0][0] and grid[0][1] and grid[0][2] == symbol) or (grid[1][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] == symbol) or (grid[2][0] and grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] == symbol) or (grid[0][0] and grid[1][0] and grid[2][0] == symbol) or (grid[0][1] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][1] == symbol)or (grid[0][2] and grid[1][2] and grid[2][2] == symbol)or (grid[0][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][2] == symbol) or (grid[2][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[0][2] == symbol):
        print("Well done!",symbol," won the game.")
        return true
    elif countmove == 9:
        print("Board Full. Game over.")


#main program
grid = [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]

countmove = 0
win = 'false'

for y in range(0,(len(grid))):

    print(grid[y])

symbol = start_player()

while countmove != 9 or win == 'false':

    countmove = 0
    row, column = getmove()
    mainturn(row,column)
    win = check_win(row,column, symbol)
```

Comment: I've changed that, but it does not exit the program after someone wins. It continues to prompt the user to enter more grid spaces.

Comment: I have changed the while counter to what you have said and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: If I remove that, the grid does not come up again after the first input.

Comment: I think the logic behind it is fine, because the loop should end if the count equals 9 or if the user gets 3 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of two things. Firstly you are resetting `count_move` value in the loop, hence it is always zero and goes in an infinite loop. Secondly you are changing the `symbol` before checking if it is a win, `check_win` routine was checking for the next symbol not the current symbol of the player. Here is the working code:

```
while countmove != 9 or win == 'false':
    row, column = getmove()
    mainturn(row,column)
    win = check_win(row,column, symbol)
    symbol = change_symbol(symbol)
```

The sub-routine change_symbol is here:

```
def change_symbol(symbol):
    if symbol == 'X':
        symbol = 'O'
    elif symbol == 'O':
        symbol = 'X'
return symbol
```

As part of good coding practice, avoid using global variables inside subroutines, it will just add up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I did my best to comment on why I did things and why I removed things. I hope this example helps you see why it cant be better to use classes when working with python. I added some other features that I think may help you as you continue to learn programming

```
import random

# Lets put all these functions into a class
class Game:

    # Lets set up the game
    def __init__(self, player_one="X", player_two="O"):

        self.player_one = player_one
        self.player_two = player_two

        # Where the game board is stored
        # Using periods instead of spaces so the players can see the possible moves
        self.game_board = [
                            [".", ".", "."],
                            [".", ".", "."],
                            [".", ".", "."]
                          ]


        # This value is to check if the game is still going
        self.running = True

        # Whos turn is it?
        self.active_player = ""

        # The tasks we HAVE to do to make the game work
        self.start_player()
        self.run_game()

    # The function is part of the Game class so we have to pass self into it.
    def start_player(self):

        # Randomly Choose a starting player
        startplayer = random.randint(1,2)

        if startplayer == 1:
            # We declared the string values in the __init__ function
            player = self.player_one
            print("Player One ({}) will start the game.".format(player))
        else:
            startplayer == 2
            player = self.player_two
            print("Player Two ({}) will start the game.".format(player))

        # Set the initial player
        self.active_player = player

    def get_move(self):
        # Seems silly to have them enter the rows and columns one by one
        #row = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))
        #column = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))

        # Show the player whos turn it is
        input_data = input("Player ({}) please choose a Column and a Row: ".format(self.active_player))

        # Default values that aren't in the game, if they arent changed they will be caught
        row = -1
        column = -1

        # Users entry all types of funky data, lets make sure its right
        try:    
            r, c = input_data.split(" ")

            r = int(r)
            c = int(c)

            if r >= 0 and r <= 3:
                row = int(r)

            if c >= 0 and c <= 3:
                column = int(c)
        except:
            print("Enter only two numbers (0, 1, or 2) seperated by a space")

        return row, column

        # This check for the grid should be its own function
        #while grid[row][column] != "":
        #   print("Invalid move.")
        #   row = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: "))
        #   column = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 2: ")) 

    def check_move(self, row, column):

        if row == -1 or column == -1:
            return False

        # If the space is blank return True
        if self.game_board[row][column] == ".":
            return True
        print("{} {} is an invalid move, try again".format(row, column))
        return False

    # Add another function to print out the board for us
    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.game_board:
            row_string = ""
            for cell in row:
                row_string = "{} {} ".format(row_string, cell)
            print(row_string)


    #def mainturn(row, column):

    # Try to avoid using globals. We'll store these in our class

    #global countmove
    #countmove = countmove + 1
    #global symbol
    #grid[row][column] = symbol

    #for y in range(0,(len(grid))):
    #    print(grid[y])
    #if symbol == 'X':
    #    symbol = 'O'
    #elif symbol == 'O':
    #    symbol = 'X'
    #return countmove

    # This is one heck of an if statement. Lets turn it into a function
    # if (grid[0][0] and grid[0][1] and grid[0][2] == symbol) or (grid[1][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[1][2] == symbol) or (grid[2][0] and grid[2][1] and grid[2][2] == symbol) or (grid[0][0] and grid[1][0] and grid[2][0] == symbol) or (grid[0][1] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][1] == symbol)or (grid[0][2] and grid[1][2] and grid[2][2] == symbol)or (grid[0][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][2] == symbol) or (grid[2][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[0][2] == symbol):

    def check_win(self, symbol):
        combinations = [
            # horizontal
            [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0)],
            [(0,1), (1,1), (2,1)],
            [(0,2), (1,2), (2,2)],
            # vertical
            [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2)],
            [(1,0), (1,1), (1,2)],
            [(2,0), (2,1), (2,2)],
            # crossed
            [(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)],
            [(2,0), (1,1), (0,2)]
            ]

        for coordinates in combinations:
            letters = [self.game_board[x][y] for x, y in coordinates]

            # If all the letters match
            if "." not in letters:
                if len(set(letters)) <= 1:
                    # returns corresponding letter for winner (X/O)
                    print("Well done {}!  You won the game!".format(symbol))
                    self.running = False
                    return True

        return False

    # Lets try another method of checking if the board is full
    #elif countmove == 9:
    #    print("Board Full. Game over.")
    #main program
    def board_full(self):
        for row in self.game_board:
            if "." in row:
                return False
        print("The game is a draw :( ")

        # Stop the game
        self.running = False

        return True

    def run_game(self):
        # While the game is not over
        while self.running != False:

            # Show the player the board
            self.show_board()

            row, column = self.get_move()

            # Is the move valid?
            if self.check_move(row, column):
                self.game_board[row][column] = self.active_player

                # Did they win?
                self.check_win(self.active_player)  

                # Change Players
                if self.active_player == self.player_one:
                    self.active_player = self.player_two
                else:
                    self.active_player = self.player_one
        # Print the winning game board
        self.show_board()

g = Game("X", "O")
    # Handled this in the class
    #grid = [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]

    #countmove = 0

    #win = 'false'

    # Turned this code into the show_board function
    #for y in range(0,(len(grid))):

    #print(grid[y])
    #symbol = start_player()

    #while countmove != 9 or win == 'false':

        # Shouldnt reset the countmove inside of the loop thats checking the countmove
        #countmove = 0

        #row, column = getmove()

        #mainturn(row,column)

        #win = check_win(row,column, symbol)
```

Example Output:

```
Player One (X) will start the game.
 .  .  . 
 .  .  . 
 .  .  . 
Player (X) please choose a Column and a Row: 0 1
 .  X  . 
 .  .  . 
 .  .  . 
Player (O) please choose a Column and a Row: 2 2
 .  X  . 
 .  .  . 
 .  .  O 
Player (X) please choose a Column and a Row: 0 0
 X  X  . 
 .  .  . 
 .  .  O 
Player (O) please choose a Column and a Row: 2 1
 X  X  . 
 .  .  . 
 .  O  O 
Player (X) please choose a Column and a Row: 0 2
Well done X!  You won the game!
 X  X  X 
 .  .  . 
 .  O  O
```